# How do you open a PDF in a new tab and show it in the browser (don't ask to download)?

Tags: java, pdf, browser, tabs, header

I have a link to a PDF and when I click on it I want it to open a new tab and render in the new tab as opposed to asking me to download it.  How do I do that?

*note, I'm asking this question so I can answer it.  This information can be pieced together from other answers, but I'd like it to be all in one place*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**To open a link in a new tab** (PDF or not) you must modify the HTML of that link from

```
<a href="/link_to_pdf.pdf">PDF</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/link_to_pdf.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

---

**To open a PDF in the browser** you must make a server side change to the response header.  In Java, you would do this:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=link_to_pdf.pdf");
```

Of key importance is the `inline`.  If you put `attachment`, your browser will try to download it instead.  [You can read more here.](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt)

Comment: Perfect ! `inline` is what is needed. For those using C# MVC, add this add follows: `HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=link_to_pdf.pdf");`

Answer (score 0):

The secret is using InputStreamResource in method response instead as ResponseEntity:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/pdf/{key}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public InputStreamResource pdf(@PathVariable("key") String key){
    InputStream file = pdfservice.get(key);
    return new InputStreamResource(file);
}
```

Comment: The code is small, simple and self explaining. If the programmer are doing a REST to download a PDF, this code I've posted is easy as ABC.